# Slick2d background

Tags: java, slick2d

I am trying to render a background image in my Slick2d window. However, it's not rendering. What's wrong?

This is the first part of my main class

```
public class SimpleGame extends BasicGame{

Image land = null;

public SimpleGame()
{
    super("Slick2DPath2Glory - SimpleGame");
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    land = new Image("bg.jpg");
    land.draw(0,0);
}
```

Here's the root tree
http://billedeupload.dk/images/4J5CQ.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do all the rendering in the render() method instead of the init() method. So something like this:

```
@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    land = new Image("bg.jpg");        
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sb, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    g.drawImage(land, 0, 0);
}
```